# Php mail() function mail is getting rejected

Tags: php, email

I have switched my old project to a new server in which i am using mail to sent mails sendmail is my mail server I am using php mail() function but it is not working properly

The php code which i am testing is this.

```
<?php 
    ini_set( 'display_errors', 1 );
    error_reporting( E_ALL );
    $from = "noreply@xyz.com";
    $to = "panel1@mailinator.com";
    $subject = "PHP Mail Test script";
    $message = "This is a test to check the PHP Mail functionality";
    $headers = "From:" . $from;
    $val = mail($to,$subject,$message, $headers);
    echo "Test email sents";
    echo $val;
?>
```

The mail is getting recived but it is getting deliverd from another address which is like this.

```
noreply@xyz.interactivedns.com
```

And the mail log is this

```
Oct 23 18:43:51 xyz2 sendmail[14831]: w9NIhp9R014831: from=www-data, size=177, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<201810231843.w9NIhp9R014831@xyz.com>, relay=www-data@localhost
Oct 23 18:43:51 xyz2 sm-mta[14832]: w9NIhpIF014832: from=<www-data@xyz.com>, size=396, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<201810231843.w9NIhp9R014831@xyz.com>, proto=ESMTP, daemon=MTA-v4, relay=www.xyz.com [127.0.0.1]
Oct 23 18:43:51 xyz2 sendmail[14831]: w9NIhp9R014831: to=panel1@mailinator.com, ctladdr=www-data (33/33), delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=relay, pri=30177, relay=[127.0.0.1] [127.0.0.1], dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent (w9NIhpIF014832 Message accepted for delivery)
Oct 23 18:43:53 xyz2 sm-mta[14835]: w9NIhpIF014832: to=<panel1@mailinator.com>, ctladdr=<www-data@xyz.com> (33/33), delay=00:00:02, xdelay=00:00:02, mailer=esmtp, pri=120396, relay=mail.mailinator.com. [23.239.11.30], dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent (Ok)
```

If i use gmail id the mail is not at all getting delivered not even in spam box

What can i do here?

Comment: Do you control `xyz.com`? If not, you're spoofing email which is going to end up getting deleted because it's fraudulent. Your envelope sender is what you're seeing and that's probably based on your IP address unless otherwise specified.

Comment: No it is just xyz aka example.com but website is something else

Comment: You'll have to check that you're properly configured for SPF and possibly DKIM before this will work. Also try a test send to a [mail testing tool](https://www.mail-tester.com) to see how you score.

Comment: 4.4/10 From mailtesting tool also what is SPF and DKIM? Honestly :( Is there a clue what may be happening here? I checked MX record is from intractivedns also i am using webmin

Comment: That's a very low score, you need at least 8.0/10 to have any hope of hitting the inbox. It provides specific recommendations on how to fix that so I'd follow up on each item. SPF and DKIM are well documented if you search for them, like [Wikipedia is a good place to start](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sender_Policy_Framework).

Comment: I am reading but how can i test it further i recently switched to a cloud hosting before that everything was working properly

Comment: Every change in your sending origin can impact deliverability, it's a complicated thing. If you're sending directly from a shared host that could be pre-flagged as being a spam originating server, so you're already at a huge disadvantage.

Comment: No it is a dedicated cloud  host recently changed to an Ubuntu machine since then mail is not going

Comment: You can make your life easier by using API of some external mail sender like mailgun. https://www.mailgun.com/

Comment: Some VM providers have their entire IP range blacklisted because they can't control outgoing SMTP activity. I know large chunks of Amazon EC2 are like this, and others are in a similar situation. You'll have to test your IP versus a [blacklist checker](https://mxtoolbox.com/blacklists.aspx).

Comment: I got this from the black list tester trying to see smtp `10/24/2018 12:32:44 AM Connection attempt #1 - Unable to connect after 15 seconds. [15.03 sec]`

Comment: Also i am able to connect from the local host through ssh to the server

Answer (score 1):

**To answer your question...**

It looks like you are missing some headers I used on a similar project a while ago. Try replacing your *$header* line with the following:

```
$message = wordwrap($message , 70);
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: ' . $from . "\r\n";
```

**Now, a word of advice...**

I struggled with the native PHP mail() function for a loooong time while stubbornly resisting other options. Believe me, you will save yourself a lot of time and trouble using something like [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer). When I finally gave in and implemented it (which was way easier than I imagined), all of the problems I was fighting through with mail() vanished. Unless you are willing to write your own complex mailing libraries, please consider [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) or a similar tool.

Comment: for php mailer i need a mail server such as google hosted from outside na?

Comment: No it is still not getting deliverd to gmail also in mailinator it is coming from different domain